# Configure IntelliJ IDEA such that source detected in git but Unregistered Vcs root detected

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea

> Unregistered Vcs root detected
>            The directory C:\Users\Andrew is under Git, but is not registered in the Settings.
>            Configure  Ignore VCS root errors

Why is this showing ?

Comment: The help section is actually useful; a "root" is a term that Intellij uses to describe a VCS feature.  In the case of git, a "root" is a directory containing a .git/ directory or a .git file (.git files are used by git worktrees).  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2018.1/settings-version-control.html?utm_content=2018.1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=CL

Answer (score 69, accepted):

1. In the error message you have the options "Configure" or "Ignore".  Click "Configure".
2. Settings window will open.  Click the "Add root" option.  In my case I only had one path on the list to choose from.  I selected that path.  Please see the image I have included below.

[image: Snapshot of Version Control settings]

3. Click Apply, then click OK.

Comment: I have two accounts synced, will configuring this override my previous setting ?

Comment: Hello Nikesh, Android Studio will use the account you have configured under File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Github.

Comment: Doesn't answer why part.

Comment: @xyz, David Argyle Thacker does in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28996058/6138589).

Comment: If you don't have that option to add root or clicking add root doesn't work then you may need to click the plus button to add it https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2711744/28329499-dff199a6-6b9e-11e7-94c8-c57f419fb723.png

Answer (score 123):

This occurs because Android Studio has detected that you have git projects imported but they have not been "registered" to track their status in Android Studio. Your project will not be negatively affected if you choose not to configure this, IntelliJ only prompts you because it has some integrated version control features that will not be able to function.

So if you want to take advantage of ItelliJ's built in version control options or just get rid of an annoying warning, its an easy fix.

Just register all of the projects you want to have the version control IDE integrations for in the `Preferences > Version Control` section. You should see this screen:

[image]

The UI is a little confusing, but all you need to do is select one of the directories under the `Unregistered roots:` section and then click the `+` button in the lower left corner of the window. If you have added all the directories you should see the `Unregistered roots:` disappear and you should no longer receive this warning.

You can select each directory and use the `+` and `-` buttons to determine which projects should use VCS in Android Studio

Comment: I agree... would be nice if the UI was intuitive, but hey, I guess programmers are supposed to solve problems? :) they should put a button under the unregsitered roots saying "register" or something else any 5th grader can understand

Comment: Finally found a clear answer. The interface is indeed unhelpful

Comment: Why would the IDE keep git projects in a status "detected but not registered" ?

Comment: On IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.3 CE this screen is under `Version Control` > `Directory Mappings`

Answer (score 3):

Look for "Version control" in preferences and set up what VCS should be used:
[image: screenshot]

You have to set this up in order to access function like revert, commit etc from the IDE.

See also, the [documentation on Version Control](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/version-control.html)

Answer (score 3):

For me, just `VCS -> Enable Version Control integration` did the trick. Having used IntelliJ in the past (Which is much similar to AndroidStudio, the latter is modeled after the former I believe), I've noticed the version control has to be enabled for each project when it's created/imported.

Answer (score 2):

Steps are given below to sort out this issue:

1. Click on Configure option
2. Select Directories under Unregistered roots
3. Hit + button at the right side of pane.

And you are good to go.