# Android Studio Unregistered VCS root detected - empty 'Project' tab

Tags: android, android-studio, github, version-control

I cannot checkout my project from hithub without this warning:
[image]

Doesn't matter with option I choose it always leaves no files under Project tab (Android filter)[image]

In Project tab (Project filter) there are only gradle files[image]

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29358524/3279023) I have to "add root" - I did...

My "Preferences -> Version Control"

[image]

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

It will always happen because every project has different,

So

Just click "Add root"

you'll see files in project explorer

Comment: When i click "add root" it act the same (2 and 3 screen)

Comment: it'll take some time